# Shopify API: Exceeded 2 calls per second for api client

Tags: shopify, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I am having a big issue on my Shopify App that I listed a couple of days ago. The core functionality of my app is an endpoint that hits the Shopify API endpoint to edit draft_orders several multiple times. I am fully aware of the rate limits of 40 requests per minute and the refresh rate of 2 requests per second.

The strange thing is the timestamp of these failed requests:

```
PUT https://****.myshopify.com/admin/draft_orders/124016722005.json [429] 09:09:16
PUT https://****.myshopify.com/admin/draft_orders/124016722005.json [429] 09:09:18
PUT https://****.myshopify.com/admin/draft_orders/124016722005.json [429] 09:09:23
PUT https://****.myshopify.com/admin/draft_orders/124016722005.json [429] 09:09:31
PUT https://****.myshopify.com/admin/draft_orders/124016722005.json [429] 09:09:47
PUT https://****.myshopify.com/admin/draft_orders/124016722005.json [429] 09:10:19
```

All of these are returning:

```
Error code: 429 (Too many request)
Error message: REASON: Exceeded 2 calls per second for api client. Reduce request rates to resume uninterrupted service.
Copy
```

As you can see there is more than 1 minute of time between the first failed request and the latest. So I am completely confused of what could be causing the issue.

**Edit**

I think I may found the problem. I was (wrongly) assuming that the user would make just one request and wait for that request to finish before sending another one. Thus this was my code in the endpoint:

```
const handleGetRequest = async (req, res) => {
  const {shop, accessToken} = await Shopify.Utils.loadCurrentSession(
    req,
    res
  );

  const client = getShopifyClient(shop, accessToken);
  
  // do stuff with Shopify client

}
```

Where `getShopifyClient` is:

```
const getShopifyClient = (shopName, accessToken) => {
  const shopify = new Shopify({
    autoLimit: { calls: 1, interval: 1100, bucketSize: 30 },
    shopName: shopName,
    accessToken: accessToken,
  });

  shopify.on("callLimits", (limits) =>
    console.log(
      `CURRENT API LIMIT STATE: ${util.inspect(
        limits,
        false,
        null,
        true /* enable colors */
      )}`
    )
  );

  shopify.on("callGraphqlLimits", (limits) =>
    console.log(
      `CURRENT API LIMIT STATE: ${util.inspect(
        limits,
        false,
        null,
        true /* enable colors */
      )}`
    )
  );

  return shopify;
};
```

Now I realize that this code will create a new instance of the Shopify class every-time I receive a new request (despite being from the same user, with the same shop name and access token).

If this is the case, would it be a solution to memoize the `getShopifyClient` return the same instance in case I send the same shop name? Something like this:

```
let memoizedClient = {}
const getShopifyClient = (shopName, accessToken) => {
  if (memoizedClient[shopName]) {
     return memoizedClient[shopName]
  }
  const shopify = new Shopify({
    autoLimit: { calls: 1, interval: 1100, bucketSize: 30 },
    shopName: shopName,
    accessToken: accessToken,
  });

  shopify.on("callLimits", (limits) =>
    console.log(
      `CURRENT API LIMIT STATE: ${util.inspect(
        limits,
        false,
        null,
        true /* enable colors */
      )}`
    )
  );

  shopify.on("callGraphqlLimits", (limits) =>
    console.log(
      `CURRENT API LIMIT STATE: ${util.inspect(
        limits,
        false,
        null,
        true /* enable colors */
      )}`
    )
  );

  memoizedClient[shopName] = shopify

  return shopify;
};
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Extrapolating on the `429`s causes by only examining those errors isn't enough to explain them! In the logs you posted, the successful requests aren't shown alongside the failed requests. Is it not plausible then, that successful requests are using up the quota without you knowing? Maybe your log with successful requests as well as failed ones might look something more like this?

```
PUT https://****.myshopify.com/admin/draft_orders/124016722005.json [429] 09:09:16
PUT https://****.myshopify.com/admin/draft_orders/124016722005.json [200] 09:09:16
PUT https://****.myshopify.com/admin/draft_orders/124016722005.json [200] 09:09:16
PUT https://****.myshopify.com/admin/draft_orders/124016722005.json [200] 09:09:17
PUT https://****.myshopify.com/admin/draft_orders/124016722005.json [200] 09:09:17
PUT https://****.myshopify.com/admin/draft_orders/124016722005.json [200] 09:09:18
PUT https://****.myshopify.com/admin/draft_orders/124016722005.json [429] 09:09:18
... and so on
```

I see you tagged the Q with `shopify-api-node`, so consider using the [`autoLimit` option](https://github.com/MONEI/Shopify-api-node#options) on the constructor of the [`shopify-api-node`](https://github.com/MONEI/Shopify-api-node) library!

```
const shopify = new Shopify({
  shopName: 'your-shop-name',
  apiKey: 'your-api-key',
  password: 'your-app-password',
  autoLimit: true,
});
```

Additionally, the [`callLimits`](https://github.com/MONEI/Shopify-api-node#shopifycalllimits) event might be a helpful debugging/resiliency tool.

Comment: Thanks for the response! The logs I posted aren't missing any success calls. Those are the only ones and are failing in a row, that's why this is so odd. On the other side, I am already using the autolimit config, in fact I have lower the threshold in order to have more margin: `autoLimit: { calls: 1, interval: 1100, bucketSize: 30 }`